# Foreign key in Complex types

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing an application with ASP.NET Core 8 and EF Core 8.

I have a value object `Address` which looks like below

```cs
public sealed class AgentAddress
{
    public string? AddressLine1 { get; private set; }
    public string? AddressLine2 { get; private set; }
    public string? PostalCode { get; private set; }

    public Country Country { get;  set; }
    public Guid CountryId { get; private set; }

    public Guid? StateOrRegionId { get; private set; }

    public Guid? CityId { get; private set; }

    private AgentAddress() { }

    public AgentAddress(Guid countryId,
                        Guid? stateOrRegionId = null,
                        Guid? cityId = null,
                        string? addressLine1 = null,
                        string? addressLine2 = null,
                        string? postalCode = null)
    {
        AddressLine1 = addressLine1;
        AddressLine2 = addressLine2;
        PostalCode = postalCode;
        CountryId = countryId;
        StateOrRegionId = stateOrRegionId;
        CityId = cityId;
    }
}
```

I am using EF Core fluent APIs to do my configuration. So the configuration is like this:

```cs
sealed class AgentConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Core.Agents.Agent>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Core.Agents.Agent> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(s => s.Id);

        builder.ComplexProperty(e => e.Address, b =>
        {
            b.Property(p => p.AddressLine1).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(AppConstants.StringLengths.Address);
            b.Property(p => p.AddressLine2).IsRequired(false).HasMaxLength(AppConstants.StringLengths.Address);
            b.Property(p => p.PostalCode).IsRequired(false).HasMaxLength(AppConstants.StringLengths.PostalCode);
        });

        builder.HasOne(s => s.Address.Country)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.Address.CountryId);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is configure the `CountryId` which is in the `AgentAddress` value object as a foreign key to my `Country` like below. The `AgentAddress` is configured as a complex type here using EF Core 8:

```cs
builder.HasOne(s => s.Address.Country)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.Address.CountryId);
```

When I'm trying to add a migration, I get this error:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The expression 's => s.Address.Country' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Is this scenario not possible, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you do this? `builder.OwnsOne(s => s.Address, address => { address.HasOne(a => a.Country).WithMany().HasForeignKey(s => s.CountryId); });`

Comment: yes, that is possible. but i need to use `ComplexProperty()` which is new in ef core 8

Comment: You would still use that too, right?

Comment: no, i nned only one option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, navigations on complex types aren't supported; this is something that we intend to explore at some point (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31245).

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the Complex Type and Foreign key. For `ComplexType`, it will use default hidden identified key.

Based on your requirement, it seems you want to make `AgentAddress` and `Country` as `ComplexProperty`. If so, you will not need to define id as foreign key.

Here is the implementation.

- Model defination

```
    public sealed class AgentAddress
    {
        public string? AddressLine1 { get; private set; }
        public string? AddressLine2 { get; private set; }
        public string? PostalCode { get; private set; }

        public Country Country { get; set; }

        public Guid? StateOrRegionId { get; private set; }

        public Guid? CityId { get; private set; }

        private AgentAddress() { }

        public AgentAddress(
                            Guid? stateOrRegionId = null,
                            Guid? cityId = null,
                            string? addressLine1 = null,
                            string? addressLine2 = null,
                            string? postalCode = null)
        {
            AddressLine1 = addressLine1;
            AddressLine2 = addressLine2;
            PostalCode = postalCode;
            StateOrRegionId = stateOrRegionId;
            CityId = cityId;
        }
    }
    public class Agent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public AgentAddress Address { get; set; }
    }
    public class Country
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

- Model Config

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Agent> Agents { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            new AgentConfig().Configure(builder.Entity<Agent>());
        }
    }
    sealed class AgentConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Agent>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Agent> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(s => s.Id);

            builder.ComplexProperty(e => e.Address, b =>
            {
                b.Property(p => p.AddressLine1).IsRequired();
                b.Property(p => p.AddressLine2).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.PostalCode).IsRequired(false);
                b.ComplexProperty(c => c.Country);
            });

            //builder.HasOne(s => s.Address.Country)
            //        .WithMany()
            //        .HasForeignKey(s => s.Address.CountryId);
        }
    }
```

- Usage Case

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var agent = new Agent { 
                //Id = 1,
                Name = "A1",
                Address = new AgentAddress(addressLine1: "AddressLine1")
                {
                    Country = new Country
                    {
                        CountryId = 1,
                        Name = "C1"
                    }
                }
            };
            await _context.Agents.AddAsync(agent);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return View();
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
        {
            return Ok(await _context.Agents.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Comment: i want to make `AgentAddress` as the only `ComplexPoperty()`, and the `CountryId` as foreign key, which here in you anwsers is not a Fk, is it?

Comment: @thanzeel Yes, it is not FK, and you will not able to make it as FK. For ComplexPoperty, it will not have real entity, if you check the database, you will see there is no such entity `AgentAddress`, For FK, it is corresponding to relationship between different entity.

Comment: @thanzeel Here is [Allow navigations and FK properties on non-collection complex types #31245](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31245)for your reference.